# python error-can only join an iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a program in pygame and I am trying to create with buttons where the user can enter their name. So basically when ever they click on the letter, then it puts that letter into a list. I recreated with about the same variables as in my game and got the same error. So if we can fix this, then I can fix my game. I am using functions so that is why you see the global thing as that is needed. Here is the code. I have looked at other forums btw but nothing that is the same as mine.

```
import glob
unknown=[]
def bob():
    global unknown
    a=('a').upper()
    unknown=unknown.extend(a)
    unknown=','.join(unknown)
bob()
```

Again, this is basically what is in my code except for the name of the function and the name of the list, other than that it is the same. The name doesn't matter though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NoneType` is not iterable. `extend` returns None.

Comment: I do not understand, I am extending it with the variable a. If your saying it doesn't have anything in unknown before the function, then how do I get it to have something without messing up the name?

Comment: don't assign `unknown` to `unknown.extend(a)`...

Comment: Gives me this error:'str' object has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: Are you calling bob() multiple times? The second time you call bob(), unknown type is a string, because of the last stmt in your function, ```unknown=','.join(unknown)```

Comment: I am adding another letter like b for example using the same format as a. I do not know how many letters are in the players name. So when even the player presses the button, it will add that to the list.