# Type error: Can only join an iterable Python-error

Tags: python, typeerror, iterable

First off, I have already looked at these posts on the same topic:

[TypeError: can only join an iterable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699726/typeerror-can-only-join-an-iterable-python)

["Can only join an iterable" python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144173/can-only-join-an-iterable-python-error)

["Can only iterable" Python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821026/can-only-iterable-python-error)

[python error-can only join an iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354027/python-error-can-only-join-an-iterable)

But sadly, none of them seem to answer my problem. I want to take a list, and sort all of the non -1 values by size, then return the -1's to their original spot. Here is my code:

```
def sortByHeight(a):
    treeLocations = []
    for everyHeight in a:
        if everyHeight == -1:
            treeLocations.append([(len(a)-a.index(everyHeight)), (a.index(everyHeight)-1)])
            a.remove(-1)
    people = sorted(a)
    for everyPair in treeLocations:
        one = everyPair[1]
        two = everyPair[0]
        people[one:two] = -1
    return(people)

sortByHeight([-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180])
```

My code throws the error: TypeError: can only assign an iterable, on line 11.
What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: you need to review your indentation

Comment: I changed my indentation, yet still get the error...

Comment: `people[one:two] = -1` <-- you're trying to assign an integer to a list slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of the assignment is a *slice* of a list. If you want to assign a value to a slice, it has to be something that Python can iterate over - lists, tuples and strings are all examples of "iterables". So

```
people[one:two] = [-1]
```

will replace the elements in the slice with the single element `-1`. You can test this out easily in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_list[2:3] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5]
>>> my_list[2:3] = -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
>>>
```

If you want to replace all the elements with `-1` then one possible formulation would use list multiplication to give a sequence of the right length:

```
people[one:two] = [-1] * (two-one)
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly address the issue you were asking about, you are trying to assign a single element to a slice (which requires an iterable). Cleaning up a few things in your example, you might do something like the following:

```
def sortByHeight(a):
    # Get indices of all -1's
    treeLocations = [index for index, height in enumerate(a) if height == -1]
    # Get list of all others
    people = [height for height in a if height != -1]
    # Sort list of others
    people = sorted(people)
    # Re-insert -1's
    for everyIndex in treeLocations:
        people.insert(everyIndex, -1)
    return(people)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally *not* a good idea to remove items from a list that you're iterating over, it can lead to unexpected results, if you're not careful. See [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). As John Machin says, it's a bit like sawing off the tree-branch that you are sitting on. ;)

Besides, removing items from a list is not that efficient: the list has to be scanned from the start until a matching item is found, and then when the item is removed all the subsequent items have to be moved down to fill up the gap. It's much better to perform a filtering operation that builds a new list from the items that you wish to keep.

---

Here's a fairly efficient way to perform that sort. The trick is to extract the items we want to sort, sort them, and then build a list that slots the sorted items into the appropriate spots.

```
def sortByHeight(seq):
    ''' sort `seq`, leaving any items equal to -1 in place '''
    # Extract items != -1
    a = [u for u in seq if u != -1]
    a.sort()
    it = iter(a)
    result = []
    for u in seq:
        result.append(u if u == -1 else next(it))
    return result

data = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
print(data)
result = sortByHeight(data)
print(result)
```

**output**

```
[-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the error I mentioned in the comment, if you're looking to do this in a much simpler manner, try this:

```
def sortByHeight(a):
    result = sorted(v for v in a if v != -1)  # first sort all non -1 fields
    for i, v in enumerate(a):  # enumerate and iterate over the original list
        if v == -1:  # if the current value is -1
            result.insert(i, -1)  # put it back into the sorted list at its original position
    return result
```

Comment: @holdenweb - given that the lists don't change lengths, `insert` is perfectly safe - even if all of the `-1` entries were at the tail of the list, `list.insert()` allows for insertion after the last index.